# Solr Query Syntax Access Field in Object

Tags: json, apache, solr

I'm looking at Data.gov which implements solr queries.  When I use a test search:

> http://catalog.data.gov/api/3/action/package_search?fq=crime

I see that in the resources array there are fields within objects:

```
    resources: [
       {
          resource_group_id: "8803cac0-41c0-4df9-9c1a-b6bf1be234d6",
          cache_last_updated: null,
          revision_timestamp: "2015-04-16T07:26:28.750291",
          webstore_last_updated: null,
          id: "4c948605-0db4-45e8-9c06-c851f05f9f37",
          size: null,
          state: "active",
          hash: "",
          description: "",
          format: "CSV",
             tracking_summary: {
             total: 7893,
             recent: 294
          },
          mimetype_inner: null,
          revision_id: "baaab1e5-d3da-493c-9459-13a250a8c8fc",
          mimetype: "text/csv",
          cache_url: null,
          name: "Comma Separated Values File",
          created: "2015-02-04T14:39:09.238366",
          url: "https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/ijzp-q8t2/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD",
          webstore_url: null,
          last_modified: null,
          position: 0,
          no_real_name: true,
          resource_type: null
       },
```

Is there a way to do filter based upon a field in that object returned?  For instance, say I want to format only objects with the format "CSV" to return.  How would I build that query?

I have tried to do something like these to no avail:

```
fq=filter:CSV
fq=filter:'CSV'
fq=resources.filter:'CSV'
fq=resources[* TO *].filter:'CSV'
fq=resources{filter:'CSV'}
```

I've been trying to find the correct pattern in examples but am having problems.

Comment: So you want a query that will return all docs if even one of the nested resources is of type CSV?

Comment: specifically i'm looking to access the format element and see what its value is